# Wrong user shown as author of the question after multiple edits

Tags: bug

For the question [How do I calculate someone's age in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9/how-do-i-calculate-someones-age-in-c) Shaik Raffi is shown as author of the question. It seems that this is based on some kind of heuristic based on the size of edits. However, the change by Shaik Raffi was rollbacked: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/9/revisions, so his changes are not even included in the final form of the question.

Comment: related if not a dupe (but cross-site on MSE):  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47474/old-usernames-stick-to-community-wiki-posts

Answer (score 3):

This happens because the question is "Community Wiki". It's no longer considered the work of a single OP, but a work by the community.

It used to be that posts become Community Wiki automatically, if enough edits (20+, IIRC) were made to them. Later this was changed, things now only become Community Wiki by manual action.

The system does indeed look at who made the most changes, and puts that username first. In this particular case, indeed it doesn't work well. The user replaced the question with an answer, and that edit was indeed reverted.

It might be worth changing the algorithm for situations were entire contributions were rolled back.

Comment: It does seem a bit off to show the name doesn't it? I wonder if it's even worth showing the name at all and just showing _26 revs, 23 users 39%_

Comment: @Bugs The percentage would need dropped too. It doesn't really make any sense without a user following it (represents the calculated percentage of the contribution from that user based on some weird formula - the user with the largest percentage is shown).

Comment: @animuson yeah sure that would be more appropriate.